# PHP creating multiple DOMDocuments in a loop issue

Tags: php, ajax, dom, document

I have a list of items to be added to the end of a base url and am trying to retrieve the html from each of these generated url's in a loop. However, I am encountering an error and i've really been struggling to fix it!

current code:

($items is just an array of strings)

```
$output = "";

foreach($items as $item) {
    $url = $baseUrl . $item;
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $dom->loadHTMLFile($url);
    $output = $output . json_encode($dom->saveHTML());
}

echo $output;
```

Can anyone tell me why I can't load multiple HTML documents like this?

Annoyingly i'm not getting any PHP error logs and the ajax xhr text is not providing any useful info, it's just returning a section of the first html page loaded as the 'error' (it seems to be able to load the first item in the array but then fails)

Comment: Are you checking your server's error logs, or just looking at the page output?

Comment: I'm looking the server's error logs and there's nothing there, the only error I seem to get is an ajax error function call

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there. This way it should do the trick:

```
$output = "";

foreach($items as $item) {    
    $url = $baseUrl . $item;
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $dom->loadHTMLFile($url);    
    $output .= json_encode($dom->saveHTML(),JSON_ERROR_UTF8);    
}

echo $output;
```

Comment: @howdybaby, could u please provide $baseUrl & items array,
or at least output of `$dom->saveHTML()`